# What value should be instead of "underscore"?

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm learning Prolog and have the following given lines:

```
Consider the following Prolog program. It contains facts regarding instructors of classes and
in which classes students are enrolled. instructor(p,c) means that professor p is the instructor
of course c. enrolled(s, c) means that student s is enrolled in course c. We want to use these
facts to answer queries concerning the professors who teach particular students.

    instructor(fibonacci, math100).
    instructor(turing, cs330).
    instructor(galileo, phys210).
    enrolled(john, math100).
    enrolled(sofia, cs330).
    enrolled(ryan, phys210).
    enrolled(lisa, math100).
    enrolled(matt, cs330).
    enrolled(lisa, cs330).
```

And then there's a question:

```
What would Prolog return given the following queries? If a query has more than one answer, list all the answers.

?- instructor(galileo, _).
?- instructor(_, ee100).
```

I've finished all of the other problems but having troubles with understanding `'_'`. What answer will Prolog produce? For `?- instructor(galileo, _).` my assumption is `phys210` but what about the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual answer for 'what will happen' is 'try it'. `_` is the "don't care" of prolog, it will anonymously unify with anything. With that, your first query:

```
?- instructor(galileo, _).
```

will succeed, with `true`. Compare that to the query:

```
?- instructor(galileo, X).
```

Which succeeds, and indeed unifies `X` with `phys210`.

Your second goal fails since there are no clauses `instructor` where the second argument is `ee100`.